# adding severity into mib file and its corresponding OId

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I have created a custom mib file i need to add the prioroty to it so while sending trap from java application i can see the severity information at my trap viewer.
my doubts are:

1;) suppose the OID for TrapDescWarn  is X.Y.Z , so for critial it would be X.Y.Z.1 ?
2:) how to load the mib file into system (i am using windows) for testing that my mib are loaded fine and i am getting the defined description.

TrapDescWarn OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX INTEGER {
            critical(1),
            major(2),
            informational(3),
            clear(4)
            }
        MAX-ACCESS read-only
        STATUS current
        DESCRIPTION
                "Warning from the payment interface"
        ::= { TrapDefs 10 }

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247959/how-to-send-the-priority-clear-major-fatal-also-along-with-the-trap

Comment: I already linked you to a post that explains how to bind variables to your outgoing notifications (in this case, an integer variable with value 1, 2, 3 or 4)

Answer (score 0):

If `TrapDescWarn`'s OID is X.Y.Z, then its OID is X.Y.Z.

`1` would be its [current] *value*, not part of its OID.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply , can you Please tell what would be the Oid for the clear, major etc. and how to load it into system.

Comment: @Satyajeet Again, those are not OIDs. They are _values_ for an object and their numbers are there in your question.

Comment: okay , so how to use this in java code if i need to send warn or major trap ?

Comment: sorry i very new to this , and not getting answers/example anywhere:(